# Complex differential forms on $CP^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Why Complex projective spaces don't admit some differential forms?

To be more specific, I know that the space of complex forms is decomposed as direct sum of holomorphic and anti-holomorphic part; given that, I don't understand why the complex projective line $CP^1$ for instance has only the scalar 0-form , and $dz \wedge \bar{dz}$.

Why 1-forms like $dz$ and $\bar{dz}$ vanish?

Answer (score 7):

It's not that $dz$ vanishes, it's that $dz$ has a pole of order $2$ at infinity in the projective line ($w = 1/z$ is a holomorphic coordinate in a neighborhood of infinity, and $dw = -dz/z^{2}$), so $dz$ is a meromorphic $1$-form, but not holomorphic. Similar remarks hold for higher dimensional projective spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Given that differential forms are independent of the choice of coordinates, if we work in inhomogeonous it seems to me that this problem is pushed away and still we can find one-forms (correct me if I'm wrong). Moreover if I use your argument I still don't see why $dz \wedge \bar{dz} $ is well defined.

Comment: The coordinate $1$-forms are certainly holomorphic and non-vanishing in inhomogeneous coordinates, but don't extend continuously to projective space. The $2$-form $dz \wedge d\bar{z}$ also doesn't extend, though $i(dz \wedge d\bar{z})/(1 + |z|^{2})^{2}$, the area form of a round metric, does. In case it helps, there exist lots of smooth $1$-forms on any manifold of positive dimension (such as global differentials); presumably you're thinking of non-trivial _holomorphic_ forms or something similar? :)